# Using SeedRandom

Tags: functions

I have the following function definition:

```
P[t_] := 
  P[t] =  P[t - 1] + μ*ED[t - 1] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.03]];
```

I want to evaluate `P` 6000 times and I want to get the same 6000 iterations of the random variable. So I basically know how to get the same 6000 iterations, but I don't know how to create a list so I can use these values in my equation.

I tried it in a simpler way with

```
a = SeedRandom[5]; 
Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.03]], {3}];
b = {1, 2, 3};
a + b
```

And the output was

```
{1 + Null, 2 + Null, 3 + Null}
```

So how can I sum up the numbers resulting from SeedRandom with other numbers?

Comment: You never assign your Table to a variable name in your "simpler" way.

Comment: Probably `a = ` should be in the row following `SeedRandom`. `SeedRandom` returns `Null` as it merely sets the seed for pseudorandom number generation.

Comment: You don't have an equation; you have a memoized definition of a recursive function.

Comment: note for your simpler case (probably what you really want) you don't even need `Table` since `RandomVariate` takes a `n` argument to generate a list.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are memoizing the values of `P[i]`, you don't need to use `SeedRandom` at all. Consider,

```
P[0] = 1;
P[t_] := P[t] = P[t - 1] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.03]]

Do[P[t], {t, 5}]
Table[P[t], {t, 5}]
```

> `{1.0187, 0.982789, 0.974296, 0.9285, 0.931482}`

The call to `Table` didn't run the function `P`; it just retrieved the memoized values. Repeating the call

```
Table[P[t], {t, 5}]
```

> `{1.0187, 0.982789, 0.974296, 0.9285, 0.931482}`

gives the same result.

Comment: you need `SeedRandom` if you want the same sequence again after a kernel restart though.

Answer (score 0):

in direct form your recursive function looks like this I think:

```
  p = P[0] + u Accumulate[Table[ED[i], {i, 0, n - 1}]] +
         Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.03], n]]
```